# android 4.4 SAF Write file into SD

Tags: android, saf

As you know,I want to save a text file into flash disk connected by otg line.On Adnroid4.4(API19),does it can create directory?I know how to save a file,but it have to click save button.I have a list of files have to save and save into different folders.So can android4.4 can realize this?I do not want to click the save button always.Can i save the file into flash disk directly by uri?

[image]

Comment: `As you know,I want to save a text file into flash disk connected by otg line`. Sorry. I think i missed something ;-). If you can use the action intent ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE then you can create directories too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can pick directories with action intent `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` then you can create directories too.

If you can only pick files (`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`) then not.

Comment: But ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE is On Api21.It doed not work on 4.4

Comment: Well then you cannot create directories is the message.

Comment: If i have 10 files to save,i have use this code to save one by one? If more files,it will be to tired.- -!

Comment: For every file the user has to act. Indeed the user will become tired.

Comment: You could zip your ten files into one zip file.

Comment: Good idea. Thank you very much.I can write it once.